# Why is the projective line a variety whereas the line with two zeros is not?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Fix some algebraically closed field k.
Consider the morphims $\psi, \phi:A^1 \rightarrow A^1\sqcup{0'}$ where $\phi(k):=k^-1$ if k is different from zero and $\phi(k):=0'$.  Likewise define $\psi$ as above but instead in the first case it assigns a non-zero point itself (instead of it's inverse).

The first case defines an object isomorphic to $P^1$, in the category of varieties but the second defines a *pre-variety* which is not a variety.  Why is this?

P.S.: by variety X I mean a pre-variety who's diagonal is closed in $X\times X$.

Thank in advance guys and gals :)

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that the line with two origins is not affine? It Is not even separated as you point out, thus not affine.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225521/separated-scheme/225811#225811

Comment: Have you tried to examine the diagonal in both cases? It's a good exercise in making sure you understand how to work with products of non-affine things. If you say where you got stuck, that helps everyone.

Comment: Cool, thanks alot guys, it was exactly as you said: an easy exersie in working with products :)